# Google ставит страницу контактов раньше главной

Tags: seo, google-search

Всем привет! Столкнулся с такой проблемой что после покупки сертификата ssl у меня гугл начал индексировать еще и страницу контактов. Все бы ничего но только вот страница контактов на первом месте, а главная на втором. И вот понять не могу в чем дело. В SEO я не сильно силен, так что решил обратится за помощью сюда, и понять почему так вышло.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Домашняя веб-страница, или главная или стартовая веб-страница, по умолчанию содержит информацию о субъекте на уровне веб-сайта. Эти эта веб-страница отличается от других веб-страниц содержание которых информирует о субъекте и сущностях только текущей веб-страницы.

Ваш веб-сайт представляет бизнес. Это означает, что по умолчанию, ваша главная страница должна представлять информацию о вашем бизнесе и о его коммерческих предложениях. Однако, главная веб-страница представляет только коммерческое предложение по доставке луковиц цветов. Содержание главной веб-страницы, как и всего веб-сайта не имеет исчерпывающей информации о организации вашего бизнеса.

Например, ваше содержание мета титла главной веб-страницы неопределенное и расплывчатое:

```
<title>Магазин луковиц цветов</title>
```

Это содержание не уникально, не имеет упоминания имени вашего бизнеса и не имеет локализации. Для создания релевантных метаданных используйте руководство Гугл **[Как создавать информативные заголовки и описания страниц для результатов поиска Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624)**:

> Заголовки страниц должны быть информативными и краткими.
> Используйте элементы бренда в заголовках, но не злоупотребляйте ими.

Оптимизируйте содержание вашего веб-сайта для мобильных устройств, которое в настоящее время **[недоступно](https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly?id=hdF08Bc-sVLPZqrJ8TqfPg)**. В настоящее время мы имеем мобильный индекс Google, ориентированный на мобильные устройства. Рейтинг вашего сайта в результатах поиска основан на сигналах из мобильной версии.

Дайте знать Гугл о всех ваших веб-страницах с картой сайта, которая в настоящее время **[недоступна на вашем веб-сайте](https://kvitosfera.com/sitemap.xml)**. Подробнее читайте руководство Гугл **[Общие сведения о файлах Sitemap](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156184)**.

Используйте **[структурированные данные](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data)** для представления вашего бизнеса и продуктов вашего магазина в богатых результатах поиска Гугл.

Зарегистрируйте ваш бизнес бесплатно в Гугл Мой Бизнес. После подтверждения регистрации вы получите УРЛ с идентификатором для панели знаний Гугл с информацией о вашем бизнесе. Установите этот УРЛ на все упоминания юридического имени вашего бизнеса в содержании веб-сайта. Это создаст связанные данные между именем вашего бизнеса, структурированными данными и панелью знаний.